# Update sync account after login

Tags: android, synchronization, account

I have created sync adapter with default sync account like the following screen shot.

[image]

And I would like to update sync account after the user logged in to the application like the following picture.

I googling a lot but I did not found any solution. I am new to sync adapter and I have no idea how to update sync adapter account after user login. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Are you want to Synv the MySQL Server data with the Local Application database ?

Comment: Yes, @RajanBhavsar. After the user login success, I want to sync their data from server. Thank you.

Comment: Please check my answer as i able to Sync my data with Database server and Local database.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Android app that 1) reads and/or writes data from a SQLite database and 2) needs to update that data periodically from another source, say a RESTful web service then one approach you can take is to hook into the Android Sync Service. I recently created an Android project with a Sync Adapter to consume and publish data to a simple Go RESTful web service and I’d like to share what I’ve learned.

Android source: https://github.com/snyderep/TeamKarmaAndroid

Go source: https://github.com/snyderep/TeamKarmaServer

Relevant parts of the Android project:
Content Provider
Authenticator and Authenticator Service
Sync Adapter and Sync Service